# window.open createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open

I'm experimenting with some new API and got stuck on this issue.

When I try to open an URI generated by `createObjectURL` with `window.open` it does nothing. But it works fine with `location.assign`.

I could not find any resource online that I could understand this behavior.

It only seems to affect Chrome.

Here is the code:

```
const DATA = [
  '<!DOCTYPE html>',
  '<html>',
    '<head>',
      '<meta charset="utf-8">',
      '<title>Hoy!</title>',
    '</head>',
    '<body>',
      '<h1>Hoy!</h1>',
    '</body>',
  '</html>'
].join('');

const TEXT_ENCODER = new TextEncoder();
const ARRAY_BUFFER = TEXT_ENCODER.encode(DATA);

const BLOB = new Blob([ARRAY_BUFFER], {
  type: 'text/html'
});

const DATA_URI = window.URL.createObjectURL(BLOB);

document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function createPage() {
  // doesn't work, don't know why
  window.open(DATA_URI, '_blank', '');

  // works fine
  // location.assign(DATA_URI);
});
```

And here's a JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/gibatronic/f97cpweh](https://jsfiddle.net/gibatronic/f97cpweh/)

Answer (score 0):

This happens randomly in Chrome, apparently depending of the contents of the file. with small zip worked fine and with big zip, does not download anything

using **location.assign** solves the problem

NOTE: setting "Settings - security" to lowest level does not solve the problem